# Second line of the Text doesn't render in the center of the row

Tags: text, react-native

I have problem with styling of the `Text`, I have two lines of the `Text`, the first line of the text appears correct on the center of the row, but second line of the code, is not in the center. How to fix that?

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Text
    style={{ marginLeft: 5, fontWeight: '500', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: ratio * 14, color: '#3c3c3c' }}
    numberOfLines={2} > {title}
  </Text>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use {textAlign:'center'} in Text Component.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, please write it as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `textAlign:'center'`,

```
   <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "row"
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          textAlign:'center', //Added
          marginLeft: 5,
          fontWeight: "500",
          fontFamily: "Arial",
          fontSize: ratio * 14,
          color: "#3c3c3c"
        }}
        numberOfLines={2}
      >
        {title}
      </Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add `textAlign` in `Text` component

```
style={{textAlign: 'center', marginLeft: 5, fontWeight:'500',fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: ratio * 14, color:'#3c3c3c'}}
                        numberOfLines={2} >
```

**Check snack demo here** : https://snack.expo.io/SJyEEwM3b

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text
          style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginLeft: 5, fontWeight: '500', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 1 * 14, color: '#3c3c3c' }}
          numberOfLines={2} > some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
                    </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```